# How do I call a function to use on a page?

Tags: functions

I want to be able to use a function called DisplayAverageRating for each of all the posts I list on a page. The function can be found here: http://pastebin.com/iXym00QM

How am I supposed to call it in my code for the average rating for each post to be shown?

This is how far I've gotten but it's not working yet:

```
<div style="">
<h3></h3>
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 200, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php if(function_exists('DisplayAverageRating')) 
{ 
DisplayAverageRating(); 
} 
?>

</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div><!-- Randomized Posts -->
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it's not a function, it's a method of `CommentRatingFieldPlugin` class, instance of which is being assigned to `$crfp` global variable.

So your should be something like:

```
global $crfp;
$crfp->DisplayAverageRating();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But is it really possible to add that to the code I shown above? It feels like it's not possible to use the foreach loop to loop through the average ratings as well, or am I wrong? I added this to the code:
http://pastebin.com/wukBknme
Instead it counts the total comments for all posts and not the amount for each post.

Comment: Sorry, @John your comment makes it seem like the actual question is different from the one asked?

Comment: The reason why I chose to take the comment thing as an example is because it displays a more obvious error. But yeah. What I'm curious about is if the loop I'm currently using is possible to bake more things into because maybe it's broke and makes the AverageRating thing to doesn't work either. As it is now something is clearly wrong as when I try to add the total comment count code to the loop it returns the following: http://pastebin.com/EreD1aaU

Comment: @John - the function uses the global `$post` variable, which isn't related to the posts you are outputting in a `get_posts` `foreach` loop, that's why they all appear to be the same value- they are all pulling from the same single post. see [access all post data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Access_all_post_data) in the codex entry for `get_posts`.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Managed to edit my code to make it work with that instead. Also managed to add the average rating thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a class method not a function. Look down at the bottom of that code and you will see...

```
$crfp = new CommentRatingFieldPlugin(); // Invoke class
```

`$crfp` is the class instance. You will need something like...

```
global $crfp;
if (isset($crfp) && method_exists($crfp,'DisplayAverageRating')) {
  $crfp->DisplayAverageRating('');
}
```

The `method_exists` check may be overkill but will prevent errors if the class changes when the plugin updates.

That function expects a parameter (`$content`) so I added an empty string, and it assumes/uses the global `$post` variable so it will only work reliably inside the Loop. It looks like it should work otherwise though.

Also, it is hooked to `the_content` so it should already be displaying in at least some places, wherever `the_content` is called.